# PetaPoco - Including Custom Partial Class Properties in WCF Response

Tags: wcf, petapoco

I have been experimenting with using PetaPoco for a small project I am working, and it has been awesome so far.

I have created some additional, non auto-generated partial classes to hold various computed values, as shown in my example below.  I can't get these additional properties to be serialized into a WCF response, but all of the properties in the auto-generated stuff serializes just fine.  I tried using [Serializable] and [DataContract] on these custom properties, but they break the WCF service altogether.

Any ideas?

```
public partial class Session
    {
        [ResultColumn]
        public int ConnectedUserCount
        {
            get
            {
                AssistedServiceDB db = new AssistedServiceDB();
                return db.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT Count(*) FROM Session_AssistedServiceUser WHERE IsConnected = 1");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things to look to get [partial WCF DataContracts](http://devlicio.us/blogs/scott_seely/archive/2010/02/09/datacontract-partial-types-and-generated-code.aspx) to work. First, if the other `Session` class is marked with the `DataContract` then this class would also need to be marked the same way. This is assuming the `ResultSession` class is also serializable and/or marked as `DataContract`. The other issue is WCF requires properties to, as a minimum, have **[private setters](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/8e63b05b-af15-4eec-97ff-c90c26054e1c/)** so the `ConnectedUserCount` property needs to be changed to have one.